# Rails Dependent Update On Associated Record

Tags: oop, design-patterns, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Given two associated models in rails (4.0),

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :subscription, dependent: :destroy
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
end
```

The above code will ensure that when an instance of `User` is destroyed, its associated record will be, too.

So far so good.

My question is, is it possible to equally easily invoke a dependent update as well, so that every time `User` is updated, `Subscription` will be updated as well?

This could look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :subscription, dependent: [:update, :destroy]
end
```

So that when `User` gets updated successfully, the associated `Subscription` will re-save, thus invoking its update filters (i.e. `before_save`, `before_update`, `after_save`, `after_update`).

Is there an elegant way to do this? If not, what is the closest way to cleanly get to this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
      has_one :subscription, :dependent => destroy, :autosave => true
```

For more details see the documentation    http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this before. Thank you.